# .jar-file fails to start on fedora gnome3

Tags: fedora, gnome3, java

form terminal, when I try to run a .jar-file I receive:

```
$ java -jar ./RemoteDroidServer/RemoteDroidServer.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at AppFrame.<init>(AppFrame.java:42)
    at RemoteDroidServer.main(RemoteDroidServer.java:16)
$
```

under Devian with LX Desktop Environment the same file runs without problem:

```
$ java -jar ./RemoteDroidServer/RemoteDroidServer.jar 
Linux
```

---

System-info

```
$ uname -a   
Linux fedora 5.5.10-200.fc31.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 18 14:21:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

relevant packages installed

```
# rpm -qa | grep -a "jdk"
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.242.b08-0.fc31.x86_64
copy-jdk-configs-3.7-4.fc31.noarch
java-latest-openjdk-13.0.2.8-1.rolling.fc31.x86_64
java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.6.10-0.fc31.x86_64
java-11-openjdk-11.0.6.10-0.fc31.x86_64
java-latest-openjdk-headless-13.0.2.8-1.rolling.fc31.x86_64

# rpm -qa | grep -a "java"
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.242.b08-0.fc31.x86_64
javapackages-filesystem-5.3.0-6.fc31.noarch
abrt-java-connector-1.1.4-1.fc31.x86_64
java-latest-openjdk-13.0.2.8-1.rolling.fc31.x86_64
tzdata-java-2019c-2.fc31.noarch
java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.6.10-0.fc31.x86_64
java-11-openjdk-11.0.6.10-0.fc31.x86_64
java-latest-openjdk-headless-13.0.2.8-1.rolling.fc31.x86_64
```

RemoteDroidServer on GitHub and GoogleCode:

```
https://github.com/alrusdi/remotedroid/tree/master/RemoteDroidServer/src
https://github.com/attilla/remotedroid/tree/master/RemoteDroidServer
https://code.google.com/archive/p/remotedroid/
```

---

**Update based on comments**

```
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

```
# cd RemoteDroidServer/ && java -jar RemoteDroidServer.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at AppFrame.<init>(AppFrame.java:42)
    at RemoteDroidServer.main(RemoteDroidServer.java:16)
```

---

**Newest Update**

I decided to try KDE-Plasma for other reasons and to my surprise, **the .jar-Program works with this DE!!**

Comment: Have you tried to run the jar in headless mode? `java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar ./RemoteDroidServer/RemoteDroidServer.jar`

Comment: @Freddy: I just did and the result is the same...

Comment: Ah, RemoteDroidServer is a gui app, right? What's the output of `java -version`? Is it 1.8.0.242?

Comment: `$ cd RemoteDroidServer/ && java -jar RemoteDroidServer.jar` .... and the GUI opens.

Comment: @Freddy: updated... I wish I knew java to supress the GUI option of the code (which hopefully is at Github (?)

Comment: @KnudLarsen: same results...

Comment: Install `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.fc31.x86_64` or select a different java version.

Comment: @Freddy: great! got it working! how did you know it had to be version 1.8 and not the latest?

Comment: well, the software is running but the communication is broken -_- ... under Debian the communication works... hmm... what to do?

Comment: Actually I used Oracle java **12** : 12.0.2

Comment: @KnudLarsen: did you already had the software or did you get it from the github-link? I ask because I got the files from http://remotedroid.net/ but the site is down since a couple of years now and I am not sure of there are differences in the source code

Comment: github : Yes. ... Please note : No updates for some years. ex1. https://github.com/omerjerk/RemoteDroid ... ex2. https://github.com/crodas/Slides ,,, which I tested : Seems I got oldest choice.

Comment: @KnudLarsen: those are two different projects with the same name. ex2 is the one I addressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with the AWT-library on a Mobian-LXDE-System (https://wiki.mobian-project.org/doku.php?id=desktopenvironments#lxde). The solution was as simple as installing the `default-jre` package.

Credits go to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241850/running-java-gui-applications-through-a-linux-terminal/5242043#5242043

I have not had the chance to test on fedora-GNOME.

---

**UPDATE**

the problem seems to have disapperes in the meanwhile thorough `dnf update` on my fedora-GNOME or it was solved by a KDE-Plasma-5-related package that was installed/updated by having two desktop environments.